# Windows Registry Key database

Tags: windows-registry, documentation

Is there a document or a website where the Windows registry keys are explained ?
Some of them are clear, however when looking for certain features it is difficult to get documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that every application vendor has their own settings, but if you look at the registry of a clean Windows operating system, it's all managed by Microsoft.

For the *most* part, I don't think you'll be able to get the answers as to what a specific setting does. On the other hand, some parameters pertaining to network settings, for example, are quite well documented - take a look at [Performance tuning for file servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/file-server/) for example.

In addition, from what I understand, there are also some default values that might not be shown in the registry - and so, if you wish to override those settings, you'll have to create a new key with the appropriate name and assign it a value.

And so, most of the time, searching around the internet for various clues is your best bet.
I'd recommend starting with the [Microsoft Docs website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/windows-registry-advanced-users).

P.S.: Look at this similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/118238/windows-7-registry-settings-documentation).